# How to get the code for reading JSON file into Excel using VBA code?

Tags: json, excel, vba

How can I get the code for reading JSON file into Excel using VBA code? Note: Output Response have already captured and stored in sResponse variable.

**VBA Code:**

```
Dim item As Variant
Dim jsonObject As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Result")
Dim i As Long
i = 3
Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sResponse)
For Each item In jsonObject("data")("judgementSummary")
ws.Cells(i, 3) = item("result")
ws.Cells(i, 4) = item("wording")
i = i + 1
Next
```

**Sample JSON Response:**

````
{"judgements":[
"id": "142555"
"date" : "636363"
"policynumber": "5364fhfh"
"judgementSummary":[
{ "code" : "253"
"result" : "3"
"wording" : "general"
}]]}}```
````

Comment: Is that the actual JSON? That's not a valid JSON format. And what is the issue with your code?

Comment: When i parse the json response from sResponse string, jsonobject holds only blank values.                            Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sResponse)  @RaymondWu

Comment: So here's the question - Your JSON is invalid so is that the actual JSON? Where did you get this JSON from? What prints out in the immediate window if you insert `Debug.Print jsonObject.Count` right after `Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sResponse)`?

Comment: @RaymondWu - got this error message  "Run time error '10001': Error parsing JSON: ^Expecting '{' or '['.                                                                                                                Function in JSONConverter file:                                                                               
        ' Error: Invalid JSON string
        Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(JsonString, json_Index, "Expecting '{' or '['")

Comment: Here s the actual response from service:{"data":{"policies":[{"policyNumber":"5555201001","policyHolderName":"Ã-Â»Ã Â¸ÃÃ","insuredName":"ãã¤ã¯","insuredGender":null,"insuredAge":null,"productName":"ç·åå»çä¿éº(ç¡è§£ç´è¿éé)ã(2018)","productCode":"860","hostErrorCode":"03"},{"policyNumber":"1411008301","policyHolderName":"ÃÂ²ÃÃ Â²ÃÃ","insuredName":"ãã¤ã¯","insuredGender":"1","insuredAge":"03","productName":"5a´ãã¨å©å·®éå½ä»çµèº«å»çä¿éº","productCode":"235","hostErrorCode":null}]},"error":null}

Comment: Actually my response JSON has some japanese language which not stored in proper format in response document. - @RaymondWu

Comment: Please edit your question and include the JSON string in the question instead.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have created new one as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the judgements and then the items for that judgement.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

    Dim jsonObject As Object
    Dim item As Variant, jmt As Object
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sResponse As String, i As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("Result")
    i = 3
    
    sResponse = _
     "{'judgements':[{'id':'142555','date':'636363'," & _
     "'policynumber':'5364fhfh','judgementSummary':[" & _
     "{'code':'253','result':'3','wording':'general'}]}]}"
  
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sResponse)
    For Each jmt In jsonObject("judgements")
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = jmt("id")
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = jmt("policynumber")
        For Each item In jmt("judgementSummary")
            ws.Cells(i, 3) = item("result")
            ws.Cells(i, 4) = item("wording")
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
    
End Sub
```